# TabbedPage not loading Child page BindingContext

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

This is my `TabbedPage` code:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MojLek.Views.OrdersPage"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
            Title="Orders">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <local:NewClaimPage IconImageSource="Add.png"  />
</TabbedPage>
```

`NewClaimPage` code:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class NewClaimPage : ContentPage
{
    NewClaimPageViewModel viewModel = new NewClaimPageViewModel();
    public NewClaimPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        viewModel.LoadPatientDoctorsCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

`OnAppearing` is not fired, `NewClaim` ContentPage not fired, `NewClaimViewModel` not fired. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you miss something in your viewmodel. Please check the suggestions below.

**Solution1:**

Due to i do not have the details for your viewmodel, I make a simple code for your reference. Set the data in your voewmodel:

```
  public class NewClaimPageViewModel
{
    public NewClaimPageViewModel()
    {
        str = "Hello";
    }
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```

Binding in your xaml: NewClaimPage

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="NewClaimPage!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="{Binding str}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Solution2:**

Or you could BindingContext in your NewClaimPage.

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:NewClaimPageViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```